# Ruby double pipe assignment with block/proc/lambda?

Tags: ruby, syntax, operators, variable-assignment, block

It is really nice to be able to write out

```
@foo ||= "bar_default"
```

or

```
@foo ||= myobject.bar(args)
```

but I have been looking to see if there is a way to write something like

```
@foo ||= do
  myobject.attr = new_val
  myobject.other_attr = other_new_val
  myobject.bar(args)
end
```

roughly equivalent in actually functional code to something like

```
@foo = if !@foo.nil?
         @foo
       else
         myobject.attr = new_val
         myobject.other_attr = other_new_val
         myobject.bar(args)
       end
```

And I suppose I could write my own global method like "getblock" to wrap and return the result of any general block, but I'm wondering if there is already a built-in way to do this.

Comment: Is it all thread safe?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use `begin`..`end`:

```
@foo ||= begin
  # any statements here
end
```

or perhaps consider factoring the contents of the block into a separate method.

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I didn't think of this.

Answer (score 4):

I usually write it like this:

```
@foo ||= (
  myobject.attr = new_val
  myobject.other_attr = other_new_val
  myobject.bar(args)
)
```

Comment: For everyone who wanted to go this way, keep in mind that this style is not rubocop-compliant: `Style/MultilineMemoization: Wrap multiline memoization blocks in begin and end.`

Answer (score -2):

```
@foo ||= unless @foo
  myobject.attr = new_val
  myobject.other_attr = other_new_val
  myobject.bar(args)
end
```